# Why is the Lie derivative a differential operator of first order?

Tags: differential-geometry

The following paragraph is from the book: Heat kernels and Dirac operators page 16

> Let $\pi: E \rightarrow M$ be a $G$-equivariant fiber bundle, where $G$ is a Lie group. The group $G$ acts on the space of sections $\Gamma( M,E) $ by the formula
> $$(g.s)(x)= g.s(g^{-1}.x)$$
> Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. We denote by $L^E(X)$, $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, the corresponding infinitesimal action on $\Gamma( M,E) $, $$L^E(X)s= \frac{d}{d\epsilon}|_{\epsilon=0}exp(\epsilon X).s ,$$
> which is called the Lie derivative. Clearly, $L^E(X)$ is a first-order differential operator on $\Gamma( M,E) $.

I don't understand the last statement of the above paragraph, namely I don't know  what does it mean that $L^E(X)$ is a first order differential operator and how to prove it!

Comment: If $E,F\to M$ are two real vector bundles, a differential operator is a $\Bbb R$-linear map $P\colon \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(F)$ such that ${\rm supp}\,P\psi\subseteq {\rm supp}\,\psi$ for all $\psi\in\Gamma(E)$. The order of $P$ at $x\in M$ is the largest non-negative integer $k=k(x)$ for which we can find $\psi\in\Gamma(E)$ and $f\in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ with $f(x)=0$ and $P(f^k\psi)_x\neq 0$. The order of $P$ is the maximum of the orders of $P$ at all points in $M$. I don't know how to make sense of your question for arbitrary fiber bundles.

Comment: You could try to write this out using local coordinates on $M$ and a local trivialization of $E$, and assume that $G$ is a matrix group.

Comment: An operator $\mathcal{O}$ is a first order differential operator iff $(\mathcal{O}s)(p)$ depends only on $p$, $s(p)$, and $d_ps$. This is often easiest to verify using (adapted) local coordinates.